# Hyphenating text inside tabularx

Tags: tabularx, hyphenation, ragged2e

I'm currently writing a thesis where hyphenation is not allowed with exception to tables. Disable Text hyphenation is working fine using:

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
```

**Now the problem is that inside tabularx** the words are larger than column width and they flow into the next column. I tried using RaggedRight while defining columns:

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
```

But still the text is not being hyphenated. Any ideas?

Requirements:

1. No Hyphenations throughout the whole document
2. Text in a table's column should not flow into the neighboring column

Below is a Mwe and a screenshot.
Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
%Used for multicolumn
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}l}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\blindtext

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Z|Z|Z|Z|Z|Z|Z|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{M|}{ \textbf{Anzahl TADs}} & \textbf{Verlustrate} & \textbf{Erfolgsdefinition} & \textbf{Misserfolgsdefinition} & \textbf{Entzündungserscheinung} \\ \hline
\textbf{Publikation} & \textbf{Insgesamt} & \textbf{Verlust} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Jung et al., 2009 & 30 & 2 & 6,7\% &  & Mangel an Osseointegrität, Mobilität des Implantates  & milde Mukositis \\ \hline
Jung et al., 2010 & 41 & 1 & 2,4\% & keine Implantatmobilität, keine unerwünschte Bewegung der Suprakonstruktion &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bad hyphenation in tabularx]

Comment: The setup of the `Z` column type, viz., `\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}`, can't be correct. Either omit `\centering` or omit `\Raggedright` and replace `\centering` with `\Centering`.

Comment: Sorry I meant "disabling text hyphenation". Corrected it in the text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
The `hyphenat` package disables hyphenation by setting \hyphenpenalty=10000\exhyphenpenalty=10000
```

So if you want to temprary enable hyphenation, set these to sensible values (e.g. 25), This is a bit lower than usual, but in a small column we want to encourage hyphenation a bit more than in regular text.

```
\newcommand{\HY}{\hyphenpenalty=25\exhyphenpenalty=25}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\HY\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\HY\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\HY\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}l}
```

Comment: I'll try this in the morning, but it looks very promising. In tables I only care that the text does not flow into the next columns. Thanks

Comment: @MoatazElmasry This is the most sensible way to handle the request.

Answer (score 2):

(edited to incorporate Piet van Ostrum's idea of changing the hyphenation penalty parameters *locally*)

From the user guide of the `hyphenat` package:

> The `hyphenat` package has an option called `none`. Use of this option prevents any
>   hyphenation *throughout the document*. If TeX is prevented from hyphenating it
>   may complain about bad line breaks and you may find bits of text sticking out
>   into the margin. If you use this option you should also consider using `\sloppy`
>   and/or `\raggedright`. [emphasis added]

Even though hyphenation is disabled globally via `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`, it is possible to re-enable it locally by resetting the hyphenation penalty parameters `\hyphenpenalty` and `\exhyphenpenalty`, as demonstrated in @PietvanOostrum's answer for the definition of the `Z` column type.

Incorporating this idea, while using `\RaggedRight` instead of `\centering` and using the `babel` package (with option `ngerman`) instead of the deprecated `ngerman` package. produces the following solution. Note that it's still a good idea to provide guidance as to what are the acceptable hyphenation points for some of the words that appear in the header row. Otherwise one would end up with cases such as `Verlus-trate`. Observe also the use of `\cline` to group the sub-headers under "Anzahl TADs".

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{ngerman} % 'ngerman' package is deprecated
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % suppress hyphenation *globally*
\sloppy 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcommand{\HY}{\hyphenpenalty=25\exhyphenpenalty=25} 
% re-enable hyphenation locally inside "Z" columns
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\HY\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X} 

\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % optional
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Z|Z|l|Z|Z|Z|Z|}
\hline
\textbf{Publika\-tion} & 
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Anzahl TADs}} & 
\textbf{Verlust\-rate} & \textbf{Erfolgs\-definition} 
& \textbf{Miss\-erfolgs\-definition} & \textbf{Entzündungserscheinung} \\ 
\cline{2-3}
& \textbf{Insgesamt} & \textbf{Verlust} &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
Jung et~al. 2009 & 30 & 2 & 6,7\% &  & Mangel an Osseointegrität, Mobilität des Implantates  & milde Mukositis \\ 
\hline
Jung et~al. 2010 & 41 & 1 & 2,4\% & keine Implantatmobilität, keine unerwünschte Bewegung der Suprakonstruktion &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this does not answer my question. I need to disable hyphenation for the whole document, but enable it inside tabularx. I updated the question with the r

Comment: Thanks for your very good remark regarding \centering. I'll try it in the morning.

Comment: @MoatazElmasry - If you *don't* want to disable hyphenation globally, you shouldn't load the `hyphenat` package with the option `none`.

Comment: Forget the last comment, I'll test your solution tomorrow. Thanks!!

Comment: @MoatazElmasry -- The first step to success is *not* to disable hyphenation globally since, well, globally means "everywhere".

Comment: Thanks Mico. This solved my problem. Also +1 for the nice example and ngerman remark. I'm giving the "Correct Answer" to Piet since he's the one who came up with the solution. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to set tables in separated documents, where you not use `hyphenat` package, compiles this documents and include to main document as pdf images:

Example of separate documents for tables:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{7}{C|}}% or better to use L clumn type
    \hline
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Anzahl TADs}} 
        &   \textbf{Verlustrate} 
            &   \textbf{Erfolgsdefinition} 
                &   \textbf{Misserfolgsdefinition} 
                    &   \textbf{Entzündungserscheinung}     \\ 
    \hline
\textbf{Publikation} 
    & \textbf{Insgesamt} 
        & \textbf{Verlust}              &   &  &  &         \\ 
    \hline
Jung et al., 2009    
    & 30 & 2 & 6,7\%    &   
         &  Mangel an Osseointegrität, Mobilität des Implantates  
            &   milde Mukositis                             \\ 
    \hline
Jung et al., 2010 
    & 41 & 1 & 2,4\%    &   keine Implantatmobilität, keine unerwünschte Bewegung der Suprakonstruktion                   &  &                \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Package `preview` is used for trimming table that hyphenation can better works. Obtained table pdf files than include in main document as

```
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{title of table}
\label{tab: ...}
    \includegraphics{path/table name}
\end{table}
```

Of course this method works fine for tables which can be placed on one page.

Comment: Thanks @Zarco but unfortunately the actual table does span over multiple pages, so this solution won't work for me